# Get the option selected of a PickerView from another UIViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a UIPopoverController with a PickerView. My problem is that i want to set the option selected in the PickerView in my first UIViewController from i opened the Popover. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a delegate in your UIPopoverController that your UIViewController inherits.

Here's a great tutorial on creating delegates: http://alexefish.com/post/15966868557/understanding-and-creating-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults:

Firstly set option which you selscted:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"objectForSelectedOption" forKey:@"option"];
```

Then in your viewController you can see what option you have choosen:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs objectForKey:@"option"];
```

Comment: Yes, but i need to update the state when the UIPopoverController is close.